# java argument with greek characters in windows

Tags: java, windows, encoding, jar

I have created a simple .jar file which is taking as argument a string with greek characters and prints it in a file.

However, I have the following issue:

When I execute the jar file from my local windows machine, the string is properly passed as argument in the jar file and the output in the file contains the greek characters I inserted.

When I try to execute the same jar file in a windows VM, the greek characters are not properly encoded and the output in the file contains unreadable characters.

I have even set the command prompt in the VM in chcp 1253 and set an environmental variable as `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` with no luck...

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Running `chcp 1253` sets your console codepage to Windows 1253, and yet you set Java to *not* use it...

If you are running your program via a batch script, save it as UTF-8 and add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to parameters for the `java` command.

If you are running your program via the console, run `chcp 65001` to switch the console to UTF-8. Also, you set the variable correctly, you can leave it that way, but you can also run Java with this option set explicitly:

```
chcp 65001
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar binks.jar
```

EDIT: If Windows is still complaining and/or messing stuff up, try changing `65001` to `1523` and `UTF-8` to `Windows-1253`. You'll lose support for most of Unicode, but there's greater chance now it will work.

Comment: I am running the program via the console, I tried the above suggestions with no luck. thanks anyway for your support